# Oracle SQL conditionally parse a json column

Tags: sql, json, oracle

in a DB table, table1 I have the following JSON in column1:

```
{
  "key1": [
    {
      "subkey1":"somevalue1",
      "subkey2":"somevalue2",
    },
    {
      "subkey1":"interestedvalue1",
      "subkey2":"interestedvalueToParseAndGet",
    }
  ]
}
```

If I do the following,

```
select JSON_VALUE(column1, '$.key1[1].subkey2') from table1
```

I'm able to get `interestedvalueToParseAndGet` from the query, which is what I'm expecting.

But I cannot guarantee that this will be the second item in the array always.

How to conditionally fetch the item from the array (who's `subkey1` is `interestedvalue1`) and get its corresponding value for `subkey2`?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle supports filtering in [JSON Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/json-path-expressions.html#GUID-AEBAD813-99AB-418A-93AB-F96BC1658618) literal, you may use it to restrict array items.

```
with sample (val) as (
  select '{
  "key1": [
    {
      "subkey1":"somevalue1",
      "subkey2":"somevalue2",
    },
    {
      "subkey1":"interestedvalue1",
      "subkey2":"interestedvalueToParseAndGet",
    }
  ]
}'
  from dual
)
select
  sample.*,
  json_value(val, '$.key1[*]?(@.subkey1 == "interestedvalue1").subkey2') as subkey2
from sample
```

| VAL | SUBKEY2 |
| --- | --- |
| { "key1": [ { "subkey1":"somevalue1", "subkey2":"somevalue2", }, { "subkey1":"interestedvalue1", "subkey2":"interestedvalueToParseAndGet", } ] } | interestedvalueToParseAndGet |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OzEiOwd-)

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to use CASE expression:

```sql
WITH            -- Sample Data:
    tbl (ID, KEYS) AS
        (   Select 1, '{
                          "key1": [
                            {
                              "subkey1":"somevalue1",
                              "subkey2":"somevalue2",
                            },
                            {
                              "subkey1":"interestedValue1",
                              "subkey2":"interestedValueFromSecond",
                            }
                          ]
                        }' 
           From Dual Union All
           Select 2, '{
                          "key1": [
                            {
                              "subkey1":"interestedValue1",
                              "subkey2":"interestedValueFromFirst",
                            },
                            {
                              "subkey1":"someOtherValue",
                              "subkey2":"notinterested",
                            }
                          ]
                        }' 
           From Dual
      )
--  M a i n   S Q L :
Select ID, CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(KEYS, '$.key1[0].subkey1') = 'interestedValue1' 
                THEN JSON_VALUE(KEYS, '$.key1[0].subkey2')
                WHEN JSON_VALUE(KEYS, '$.key1[1].subkey1') = 'interestedValue1' 
                THEN JSON_VALUE(KEYS, '$.key1[1].subkey2')
           END "INTERESTED_VALUE" 
From tbl
--
--  R e s u l t :
--  ID  INTERESTED_VALUE
--  --  --------------------------
--   1  interestedValueFromSecond
--   2  interestedValueFromFirst
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `JSON_TABLE`, and following worked:

```
SELECT subkey2 
     FROM table1,
     JSON_TABLE(
       json_data,
       '$.key1[*]'
       COLUMNS (
         subkey1 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.subkey1',
         subkey2 VARCHAR2(100) PATH '$.subkey2'
       )
     )
WHERE subkey1 = 'interestedvalue1';
```

Comment: It may be better to specify `outer apply` or `left join lateral` with a subquery to `json_table` to allow null value on absent element (which will be aligned with `json_value` behavior)